# Chrome - Save As not using correct filename when displayed inline

Tags: google-chrome, http, content-disposition

I have a collection of files that I am storing in S3, and for various reasons, the actual name of the S3 object is not the original filename. But I am using the Content-Disposition header to set the filename I want the browser to use. And it works correctly for certain files in certain browsers. But for some reason, for inline text files in Chrome it doesn't.

Here's an example: https://dev-download.veoci.com/mapicons/4.txt
The object name (or I guess technically the last part of the path of the object name) is `4.txt` but I set the Content-Disposition filename to be `hello.txt`

So why does Chrome save it as `4.txt` and how do I fix it?

Note - this is specific to the situation where we view the file inline and then press Save. If the Content-Disposition is `attachment` to start out with, the correct filename is used.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of inline text files in Chrome, the browser may use the object's actual filename instead of the suggested filename in the `Content-Disposition` header. You may try to work around this by setting your file's `Content-Type` header to a MIME type that Chrome recognizes as a downloadable file, such as `application/octet-stream`. This may trick Chrome into treating the file as downloadable instead of displaying it inline, using the suggested filename in the `Content-Disposition` header.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm looking for. I _do_ want the file to show inline. I just want to control what filename is suggested when they click Save As...